# JAVA - Selenium WebDriver - Assertions and Waits

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, wait, assert, assertion

I am having a problem with my Assertion, or rather with the "time" the assertion is being executed. So, the assertion is working as it should, however, it is going too fast, as it is executing without waiting for the page it should be targeting to load. Which means that the assertion is failing the test.

Having this in mind, I tried searching around how to add a "wait" to the assert to make it wait for the page to load before running, but with no success.

So, would anyone, please be able to help with this, as in how would I code so, that the assert "waits" for the page to load and then executes?

I've tried adding the wait to the header method, i tried adding the wait to the test script, but no success.

```
public class test1 extends DriverSetup{

    //Here we are setting the method to use the homePage
    private HomePage homePage = new HomePage(getDriver());

    //Here we are setting the method logInPage
    private AuthenticationPage authenticationPage = new AuthenticationPage(getDriver());

    //Here are setting the method CreateAccountPage
    private CreateAccountPage createAccountPage = new CreateAccountPage(getDriver());

    //Here we are setting the method to access the Website HomePage with the driver
    private void accessWebsiteHomePage (){

        getDriver().get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
    }

@Test
    public void CreateAccount() {

        accessWebsiteHomePage();

        //Log in
        homePage.logInBut();

        //Authentication page "Create a new account" box
        authenticationPage.setCreateAccountEmailAddress(emailGenerator.Email());
        authenticationPage.CreateAccountButtonClick();

        Assert.assertEquals("CREATE AN ACCOUNT", createAccountPage.HeaderCheckRightPage());
```

The assert should be targeting the "CREATE AN ACCOUNT" page, but it is targeting the "AUTHENTICATION" page, which comes before it, hence the test fails as the "actual" value being printed is the "AUTHENTICATION" page, not the "CREATE AN ACCOUNT" page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an explicit wait.  Here is one that will wait for the title to be equal to something:

```
private ExpectedCondition<Boolean> titleIsEqualTo(final String searchString) {
    return driver -> driver.getTitle().equals(searchString);
}
```

You can make it more reliable by forcing the case of what you want to match like this:

```
private ExpectedCondition<Boolean> titleIsEqualTo(final String searchString) {
    return driver -> driver.getTitle().toLowerCase().equals(searchString.toLowerCase());
}
```

You would then need to put the following in before your assertion:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 100);
wait.until(titleIsEqualTo("CREATE AN ACCOUNT"));
```

I'm making the assumption that by header you mean the page title since you haven't shown the code that collects the header.

***Edit***

A non-lambda version of the above ExpectedCondition is:

```
private ExpectedCondition<Boolean> titleIsEqualTo(final String searchString) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return driver.getTitle().toLowerCase().equals(searchString.toLowerCase());
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi there @Ardesco, thank you for your reply. <p>Please do accept my appologies for the late reply. I have tried your solution particularly this part: </p> <p> private ExpectedCondition<Boolean> titleIsEqualTo(final String searchString) {
    return driver -> driver.getTitle().toLowerCase().equals(searchString.toLowerCase());
}</p> But it is giving me an error, with a red line under it saying: "Incompatible types. Required: org.openqa.selenium.suport.ui.ExpectedCondition<java.lang.Boolean> Found: boolean   Am I missing somehting here? Or did you miss something while you were typing?

Comment: Have you got your project language level set to Java 8 or higher in your IDE? The above is a Java 8+ Lambda, so if your project language level is set to Java 6 it won't understand it.

Comment: Yup, it is set as "8".

Comment: Does the non-lambda version I've added fix it for you?

Comment: Now it returns two errors: Error:(30, 16) java: cannot access java.util.function.Function
  class file for java.util.function.Function not found

Comment: Second error: Error:(69, 13) java: method until in class org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.function.Function<? super org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver,V>
  found: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<java.lang.Boolean>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) V
    (argument mismatch; org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<java.lang.Boolean> cannot be converted to java.util.function.Function<? super org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver,V>)

Comment: What version of Selenium are you using?

Comment: Selenium version: 3.141.59

Comment: Have you got the following imports:  ```import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;```?

Comment: Yup, I do indeed have them both!